# Multiprocessing does not complete (does not seem to be joining).

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a problem in which the first step is to come up with all the possible unique combinations of the nine digit integer with only the numbers 1-9 (9!). I have written a function that works just fine, however it is pretty slow, so therefore I am now trying to use multiprocessing to split this up into 4 processes.

I have added some measures to try and find where my problem lies (adding a 'done' statement after the function completes its set) and it seems to be stuck just before the .join() function. Monitoring my CPU history, I do see the 4 cores rise to 100% for a few minutes then fall, but then never proceeds or gets to the final length print statement. Has anyone run into this problem before?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime

output = mp.Queue()


def permutations(ourRange, output):
    print(len(ourRange))
    print(output)

    for p in ourRange:
        p = str(p)
        if ("1" in p) and ("2" in p) and ("3" in p) and ("4" in p) and ("5" in p) and ("6" in p) and ("7" in p) and ("8" in p) and ("9" in p):
            output.put(p)
    print("done")
    return ""



p1 = mp.Process(target=permutations, args=(range(123456789, 339506172), output))
p2 = mp.Process(target=permutations, args=(range(339506172, 555555555), output))
p3 = mp.Process(target=permutations, args=(range(555555555, 771604938), output))
p4 = mp.Process(target=permutations, args=(range(771604938, 987654322), output))

processes = [p1, p2, p3, p4]


for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

print("joined")

results = [output.get() for _ in range(output.qsize())]
print(len(results))
```

Comment: The number of possible 9 digit numbers consisting solely of the digits 1-9 (i.e. no 0s) is 9^9 (= 387,420,489), which is considerably larger than 9! (= 362,880)...

Comment: Yes, that is with repeating digits as well. I am trying to use each digit only once (like sudoku), sorry should have made that more clear!